# How to find an element based on its parent's sibling's child's text with Xpath

Tags: c#, html, xpath

Having a piece of html document like this:

```
<div class="main">
   <div class="first">
         **<div id="my_target"></div>**
    </div>
    <div class="second">
       <p class="child">I need to find  preceding or nearest sibling's child with id=my_target based on this text</p>
       <div>...</div>
        <div/>
    <div>....</div>
   </div>
```

Can someone help me to find an element with `id=my_target` and having parent whose sibling's child element p contains some specific text using XPath?

Comment: Would that be it's cousin's text, then? ;p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your explanation step by step:

```
//div[@id="my_target" and ../following-sibling::div/p="some text"]
```

Demo (using [`xmllint`](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html)):

```
$ cat test.html
<div class="main">
   <div class="first">
         <div id="my_target">This is what I want to find</div>
    </div>
    <div class="second">
       <p class="child">some text</p>
       <div>...</div>
    </div>
    <div>....</div>
</div>
$ xmllint test.html --xpath '//div[@id="my_target" and ../following-sibling::div/p="some text"]'
<div id="my_target">This is what I want to find</div>
```